# How to set a value for a select options based on it's index number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set a value to a select options based on it's index number, or maybe in other words how to select the select options based on it's index number

```
   <select name="size" id="size">
      <option value="a" hidden selected>Select Size</option>
      <option value="1">Normal</option>
      <option value="2">Large</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: By index you mean the number in the value attribute?

Answer (score 2):

The `select` element ([`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)) has an array-like property called [`options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) that you can index into:

```js
const select = document.getElementById("size");
console.log(select.options[0].value);
console.log(select.options[0].text);
```

```html
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="a" hidden selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Large</option>
</select>
```

Or with jQuery:

```js
const $select = $("#size");
const select = $select[0];
console.log(select.options[0].value);
console.log(select.options[0].text);
```

```html
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="a" hidden selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Large</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to set a value to a select options based on it's index number

```js
$('#size option').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).index())

  //! test
  console.log($(this).index())
  // test!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="a" hidden selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Large</option>
</select>
```

> or maybe in other words how to select the select options based on it's
>   index number

```js
$('#size option').eq(2).prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="a" hidden selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Large</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set option as selected you can use:

```
$('#size :nth-child(index)').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```js
$('#size option').each(function() {
  let index = $('#size option').index(this);
  console.log($('#size option')[index].value, ':', $('#size option')[index].text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="a" hidden selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Large</option>
</select>
```